# Does Python's sort()/sorted() function call its optional 'key' argument O(n) times or O(n log n) times?

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

Suppose `apples` is a list of n apples and I have a function `apple_evaluator(apple)` that evaluates the 'goodness' of an apple. To sort `apples` by 'goodness' I use `apples.sort(key = apple_evaluator)` or `sorted(apples, key=apple_evaluator)`.

Will `apple_evaluator` get called O(n) times (e.g. Python precomputes `apple_evaluator(apple)`  for each `apple` in `apples` then sorts `apples` using these values) or O(n log n) times (e.g. Python computes recomputes the `apple_evaluator` values each time the sort makes a comparison)?

Answer (score 5):

Just test:

```
count = [0]

def _sort_key(x):
    count[0] += 1
    return x


a = list(np.random.rand(12))

print count
a.sort(key=_sort_key)
print count, len(a)
```

The answer is O(n).

Comment: Couldn't `count` be simply a varible?

Comment: @thefourtheye, yes it's just necessary to put 'global count` in the `_sort_key` function to allow it to be rebound in there

Comment: @gnibbler `count` is a list in this case. Thats a bit overkill, right? That could have been just a global variable `count`.

Comment: @thefourtheye, yes. I think it would have been clearer to just make it a global. However the list trick is handy in Python2 closures sometimes because you don't have the `nonlocal` keyword

Comment: I understand lists, but have never used `global`  so I wrote what I understand ;)

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of replacing `cmp` with `key` was to have O(n) calls to the key function. This is known as the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) or  decorate-sort-undecorate

Before the advent of the `key` parameter, it was found that `cmp` was nearly useless because it was more efficient to do this procedure. where `f` is the key function

```
L = [(f(i), i) for i in L]                           ## decorate
L.sort()    # there was no "sorted()" at the time    ## sort
L = [i[1] for in L]                                  ## undecorate
```